# How locate the pseudo-element ::before using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I'm using Selenium Python to locate label element.I want to use **::before** to locate it,because this is a pop window.

```
 <div class="crow" grp="0" grpname="Pizza Size">
    ::before
    <label class="label0" cid="1">
    <input type="radio" name="0" coname="M" sname="" price="9.99" value="392">M<b class="ip">9.99</b>
    </label>
    <label class="label0" cid="1"><input type="radio" name="0" coname="L" sname="" price="11.99" value="393">L<b class="ip">11.99</b>
    </label><div style="clear:both">
    </div>
    </div>
```

I have no idea how to use ::before to locate it,any friend can help?

Comment: Why do you want to locate the `::before` element? What is your exact usecase?

Comment: It can be done from the browser side with window .getComputedStyle

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### [Pseudo Elements](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/)

A CSS [pseudo-element](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp) is used to style specified parts of an element. It can be used to:

- Style the first letter, or line, of an element
- Insert content before, or after, the content of an element

---

### ::after

`::after` is a pseudo element which allows you to insert content onto a page from CSS (without it needing to be in the HTML). While the end result is not actually in the DOM, it appears on the page as if it is, and would essentially be like this:

*CSS*:

```
div::after {
  content: "hi";
}
```

---

### ::before

`::before` is exactly the same only it inserts the content before any other content in the HTML instead of after. The only reasons to use one over the other are:

- You want the generated content to come before the element content, positionally.
- The `::after` content is also "after" in source-order, so it will position on top of `::before` if stacked on top of each other naturally.

---

### Demonstration of extracting *properties*  of [pseudo-element](/questions/tagged/pseudo-element)

As per the discussion above you can't locate the `::before` element within the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) but you can always be able to retrieve the contents of the *pseudo-elements*, i.e. `::before` and **`::after`** elements. Here's an example:

To demonstrate, we will be extracting the content of **`::after`** element (snapshot below) within this [website](https://meyerweb.com/eric/css/tests/pseudos-inspector-test.html):

[image: after_element]

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://meyerweb.com/eric/css/tests/pseudos-inspector-test.html')
  script = "return window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('body>p.el'),':after').getPropertyValue('content')"
  print(driver.execute_script(script).strip())
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  " (fin.)"
  ```

This console output exactly matches the **value** of the **`content`** property of the **`::after`** element as seen in the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp):

[image: after_content]

---

### This usecase

To extract the value of the **content** property of the `::before` element you can use the following solution:

```
script = "return window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('div.crow'),':before').getPropertyValue('content')"
print(driver.execute_script(script).strip())
```

---

### Outro

A couple of relevant documentations:

- [Document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- [Window.getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong, then, Selenium doesn't provide any function or API call for this. You can try parsing the html and then finding the tag using a simple regular expression.

Comment: ::after & ::before are a pseudo element which allows you to insert content onto a page from CSS. Just clicking the container is same. A quick overlook on the documentation didn't show any particular function for this.