# Not able to get element by xpath inside div with ::before

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, web-scraping, pseudo-element

I need to get the list of web elements by using web driver object

```java
findElements(By.xpath(""));
```

I get the list by using xpath as `//*[@class=\"providers-list clearfix\"]`.However, I get an error whenever I try to fetch element inside

```html
<div class="providers-list clearfix">::before 
  <div class="data-container">..</div>
</div>
```

This xpath gives me error:

> //*[@class=\"data-container\"]" as no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@class="data-container"]"}

Answer (score 1):

Presence of [pseudo-element](/questions/tagged/pseudo-element) e.g. [::before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59689722/how-locate-the-pseudo-element-before-using-selenium-python/59706267#59706267) implies that the element is either:

- Styled or
- Inserted before some content

So the element is dynamic in nature and to identify the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *visibilityOfElementLocated()* and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.providers-list.clearfix div.data-container")));
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='providers-list clearfix']//div[@class='data-container']")));
  ```

Answer (score 0):

please use this X-path - //*[contains (@class, ‘clearfix')]

Comment: thanks, Abhishek it still gives me an error . Actually I need to fetch data from div inside class="data-container".

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to access from the object which did findElements? This is how it works ideally:

```
    List <WebElement> myList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class=\"providers-list clearfix\"]"));
                for(WebElement eachList:myList)
                {
         System.out.println(eachList.findElement(By.xpath("div[1]")).getText());
                }
```