# How to write the xpath for an element where ::before tag is involved

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to click a select element which is followed by `::before` tag. Can anybody please help me to write the XPath or the CSSselector path for the below HTML

[image]

Below is the XPath that I have written to click on the month

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'pika-single is-bound left-aligned bottom-aligned')]/div[contains(@class,'pika-lendar')]/div[contains(@class,'pika-title']/div[1]/select[contains(@class,'pika-select pika-select-month')]"));
```

Comment: *::before tag* doesn't really affect your selectors. Just try to use Select class to handle `select` node and search by CSS selector `"select.pika-select-month"`

Answer (score 0):

### [Pseudo Elements](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/)

A CSS [pseudo-element](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp) is used to style specified parts of an element. It can be used to:

- Style the first letter, or line, of an element
- Insert content before, or after, the content of an element

---

### ::before

`::before` is a pseudo element which allows you to insert content onto a page from CSS (without it needing to be in the HTML). While the end result is not actually in the DOM, it appears on the page as if it is.

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussion in:

- [How locate the pseudo-element ::before using Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59689722/how-locate-the-pseudo-element-before-using-selenium-python/59706267#59706267)
- [Not able to get element by xpath inside div with ::before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60360940/not-able-to-get-element-by-xpath-inside-div-with-before/60367247#60367247)

---

### This usecase

As the date picker is a [html-select](/questions/tagged/html-select) menu you have to use the [Select](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.select.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.select) *Class*. Moreover, as you have to interact with the [drop-down-menu](/questions/tagged/drop-down-menu) you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()`.

To select the `<option>` with text as *January* from the [dropdown](/questions/tagged/dropdown) you can use you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  WebElement elem = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("select.pika-select.pika-select-month")));
  Select mySelect = new Select(elem);
  //selecting the item January by value
  mySelect.selectByValue("0");
  ```
- Using *xpath* and in a single line:

  ```
  //selecting the item January by visible text
  new Select(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//select[@class='pika-select pika-select-month']")))).selectByVisibleText("January");
  ```

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to select an option from a dropdown through Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49772710/how-to-select-an-option-from-a-dropdown-through-selenium-webdriver/49777340#49777340)
- [How can I get all elements from drop down list in Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768318/how-can-i-get-all-elements-from-drop-down-list-in-selenium-webdriver/63093682#63093682)