# how to identify css selector ::before in selenium is not working

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I am trying to use Selenium to get all element in the list  ::before pseudo-element. I can't save data into the list.

**Scenario:** I want to all data into the list where data in li and a tag

Here is what the DOM looks like:

[image]

I am using selenium + python

**This code is hovering to main category nav 'Women':**

```
element_to_select = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='nico-main-header']/nav/ul/li[1]")
hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element_to_select)
hover.perform()
driver.implicitly_wait(15)
```

**Print all li achor tag :**

```
ele = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("ul .row .col-md-3:first-child ul li")

print(ele)
```

** but li anchor tag is not coming while printing the ele.

Comment: Do you want all li elements in a list?

Comment: Yes. I want to all <a> tag data where <li> tag. Like: Woollies at 40% off, New Arrivals and all li a tag data

Comment: Can you please post the code which you have already tried?

Comment: This code is hove to main category nav: 

element_to_select = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='nico-main-header']/nav/ul/li[1]")
hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element_to_select)
hover.perform()
driver.implicitly_wait(15)

Print all li achor tag :
ele = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("ul .row .col-md-3:first-child ul li")

print(ele)

Comment: Please post the selenium code it whatever programming language you are trying java, python or javascript.

Comment: I am using python + selenium.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this code: 
For a tag**

```
my_a_tag_datas = []      //empty list
a_data = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")   //a tag from web driver
for a_tag_data in a_data:      
    a_tag_data_taxt = a_tag_data.text    // a tag element data convert to text
    my_a_tag_datas.append(a_tag_data_taxt)   //  a tag whole data save in list
print(my_a_tag_datas)    // print list data
```

**For li tag: same code just please replace "a" to "li"**

***Note: If you save all element rather then text then please append a_tag_data where i append  a_tag_data_taxt***

Comment: It's not working while running the code. Only Women string are print and all data are empty.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: This is not an optimal solution.I am using python for the first time and not have much hands on with selenium.

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.col-md-3').find_elements_by_tag_name('a')

  for a_tag_data in elem:
    a_tag_data_text = a_tag_data.text
    my_a_tag_datas = my_a_tag_datas + a_tag_data_text

print(my_a_tag_datas)
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Pseudo Elements](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/)

A CSS [pseudo-element](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp) is used to style specified parts of an element. It can be used to:

- Style the first letter, or line, of an element
- Insert content before, or after, the content of an element

---

### ::before

[`::before`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59689722/how-locate-the-pseudo-element-before-using-selenium-python/59706267#59706267) inserts the content before any other content in the HTML instead of after. The only reasons to use one over the other are:

- You want the generated content to come before the element content, positionally.
- The `::after` content is also "after" in source-order, so it will position on top of `::before` if stacked on top of each other naturally.

---

### This usecase

To extract all the texts within `<a>` tag using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491)  and *Python* you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://nthqibord.com/2019/08/15/pemimpin-pkr-pertahan-tun-mahathir/")
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a#main-category-menu[href='/shop/women/'] + ul.top-nav-border ul li>a")))])
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://nthqibord.com/2019/08/15/pemimpin-pkr-pertahan-tun-mahathir/")
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@id='main-category-menu' and @href='/shop/women/']//following::ul[@class='top-nav-border']//ul//li/a")))])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Not working coming error, TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given