# Radio option selection that populates pseudo ::before & ::after elements using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I need some help with identifying which radio option is selected. The webpage I am dealing with has two radio options Yes and No. Below is the HTML code when option Yes is selected. Note that `::after` is populated in the `label for` tag for it.

```html
<div class="rule-scope-radio-list">
    <label class="vdl-radio">
        <input id="radio_HlzYBaCpA3xEjRkH0fgU-" type="radio" class="vdl-radio__input" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" value="true">
        <label for="radio_HlzYBaCpA3xEjRkH0fgU-">
          ::before
          "Yes"
          ::after
        </label>  
    </label>
    <label class="vdl-radio">
        <input id="radio_KHhle2RxBSrl5Vb_n7Eit" type="radio" class="vdl-radio__input" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" value="false">
        <label for="radio_KHhle2RxBSrl5Vb_n7Eit">
          ::before
          "No"
        </label>
    </label>
</div>
```

When option No is selected on the webpage only thing that changes in the HTML code is `::after` is removed from Yes option and gets populated for No option.

I tried Selenium's `isSelected()` method but it always returned 'false' when I am expecting 'true' for Yes option.

As a second alternative I wrote  below Java code that also didn't work. It is returning `null`. My idea was to get the entire `input for` tag and then use string.contains() method to check if it has `::after` in it. Because when I execute below JavaScript on browser console, it returned entire `input for` tag with both `::before` and `::after` elements in it.

```java
public String yesOrNoSelected(){
        String tag = "";      
        List<WebElement> radioOptions = findElementsByXpath(".//div[@class='rule-scope-radio-list']/label");

        //Iterate thru both radio options and execute the JavaScript.

        for(int i = 1; i <= radioOptions.size(); i++) {
                String script = "return document.querySelector('div#rule-scope-radio-list> label:nth-of-type("+i+") label', null);";
                JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
                tag = (String) js.executeScript(script);
                System.out.println(tag);
            }        
        return tag;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to avoid the _CSS_ `::before` and `::after` unless you are concerned with the stylesheet.

Comment: @DebanjanB - it is how the UI framework is designed that builds elements/attributes this way. Any workable solution is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I never try Selenium with java but here i do some code for you. I am not damn sure it will work or not.but i suggest you to use cssSelector for checking RadioButton is checked or not.

```
public String yesOrNoSelected(){
    String tag = "";      
    List<WebElement> radioOptions = findElementsByXpath("//div[@class='rule-scope-radio-list']");

    //Iterate thru both radio options and execute the JavaScript.

    for(int i = 1; i <= radioOptions.size(); i++) {
    var val = radioOptions.get(i).findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value='true']"));
    if(val!=null){
        tag = radioOptions.get(i).getTagName();
        System.out.println(tag);
    }                
  }        
  return tag;
}}
```