# How to extract text between ::before and ::after

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, pseudo-element

[image]

I would like to extract the text between ::before and ::after into a string. How can I use a for loop to extract all the text in selenium Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text *`i`* is in between the `::before` and `::after` [*pseudoelements*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59689722/how-locate-the-pseudo-element-before-using-selenium-python/59706267#59706267). So to extract the text you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.kbkey.button.red").text)
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='kbkey button red']").text)
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468629/python-selenium-wait-until-element-is-fully-loaded/50474905#50474905) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over/48056120#48056120):

- Using *CSS-SELECTOR*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.kbkey.button.red"))).text)
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='kbkey button red']"))).text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

---

### References

Link to useful documentation:

- [*get_attribute()*](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method *gets the given attribute or property of the element*.
- [*text*](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns *the text of the element*.
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)

Answer (score 1):

`::before` and `::after` are just a pseudo elements.
Here you can extract the text from the `div` element itself.
In case there are several `div`s with class `kbkey button red` you can do something like this:

```py
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.kbkey.button.red")
for button in buttons:
    print(button.text)
```

Comment: this totally worked for me.  I saw the print statements in my use case showing the text in the 2nd of of 3 loops.  Thanks!

Comment: To add some context... It appears when ::before and ::after are present you should use .find_elements.  The reason is this situation creates a 3 item array and the middle item is your text!  So, to grab that, set up a variable prior to this point that gets the value if text is found.  Also, I had to call .text in the for loop on the for-loop variable representing the selenium object.

Comment: @rom You are more than welcome! And thanks for the detailed explanations!