# Can´t access pseudo ::before ::after element in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I want to get the text within a var tag which lies within a pseudo class:
`::before ... <var class="added">Element</var> .. ::after`

I tried
[How locate the pseudo-element ::before using Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59689722/how-locate-the-pseudo-element-before-using-selenium-python)
And also the usual ways like:

```
x = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("added")

elem = [i.text for i in x]
```

Or trying to access it via the parent element.
I always get an empty list as a result.
Does anyone here have an idea what I´m doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Not sure if my edit solved the issue you´re pointing out. Maybe I don´t understand my own underlying problem that I´m trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried beautiful soup instead of selenium? This may be a bad workaround but it helped me in many such cases.

Comment: I would like to stick to selenium as I feel this should be possible.