# Python Selenium: Blank output being returned instead of actual span text

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

[image]

I want the text 'March' from the element from the wesbite: https://www.greateranglia.co.uk/

Step 1: Click calendar icon

Intention: Once the calendar appears, I want to fetch the months text.

Step 2: When I right click on the element and get Selector code this is what I get:-

```
#dp1711106126734 > div > div.ui-datepicker-group.ui-datepicker-group-first > div > div > span.ui-datepicker-month
```

Output I receive:-
System is unable to locate this element

```
def get_month(self, element):
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
        left_month = self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, element)
        return left_month.text
get_month('#dp1711106126734 > div > div.ui-datepicker-group.ui-datepicker-group-first > div > div > span.ui-datepicker-month')
```

Inspect Element Screenshot:-
[image]

Actual Output:-
[image]

Comment: You have pseudolements '::before' and they need separate execution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59689722/how-locate-the-pseudo-element-before-using-selenium-python

Comment: @MortenB Could you please help me in forming the exact CSS locator ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not particular about using `CSS_SELECTOR` strategy, try `XPATH` locator strategy as below.

You can try the below XPath expression:

```
(//span[@class='ui-datepicker-month'])[3]
```

Explanation:

- `(//span[@class='ui-datepicker-month'])[3]` selects the third `<span>` element with the class `ui-datepicker-month` in the HTML document

Change the below code:

```
left_month = self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, element)
```

TO:

```
left_month = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//span[@class='ui-datepicker-month'])[3]")
```

**UPDATE:**

Here is full working code with in-line explanation:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("https://www.greateranglia.co.uk/")

# Click on Allow all cookies button
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Allow all cookies']"))).click()

# Click on Enter origin station text box
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "from-buytlbf"))).click()

# Click on calendar icon
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//a[@class='dpg-btn p-0'])[1]"))).click()

# Locate left month and print it
left_month = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//span[@class='ui-datepicker-month'])[3]")))
print(left_month.text)

# To click on date (23rd) in the left calendar
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//a[text()='23'])[3]"))).click()
time.sleep(20)
```

Console result:

```
March

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: I appreciate your help. However the code returns empty value when I am trying to fetch the span text. I believe it is because there are 2 ui-datepicker-month span classes on the page.

Comment: Check the full code in the answer. Try to use explicit waits effectively. Try it and let me know the outcome.

Comment: Thank you Shawn. I will keep the waits in mind. Thank you so much once again.

Comment: Could you also please help me in picking up a desired date and clicking it ? For eg. I want to select 23rd March, then how should I go about it ?

Comment: I added the code to select 23rd in the answer. Cheers.

Comment: FYI - `(//a[text()='23'])[3]`: for 23rd from left calendar. `(//a[text()='23'])[4]`: for 23rd from right calendar.

Comment: Thank you so much. I highly appreciate your help. It worked. I am trying to learn from your answers but I am extremely struggling. For eg. I am trying to click the '>' at the right corner of the calendar. Hence, I inspect the elements and try to modify like you did for span class , something like this: //a[@class='ui-datepicker-next.ui-corner-all::after']

I believe it should have worked, but apparently it did not. What is the catch here? I mean, can you guide me how do I learn inspecting correct elements?

Comment: Could you please me find the locator to locate '>' top right arrow as well? I have been stuck from past couple of hours. Thank you.

Comment: Use this XPath expression - `(//a[@class='ui-datepicker-next ui-corner-all'])[2]`

Comment: Thanks a lot yet again. But could you please explain what [2] here ? What does it signify here?

Comment: On the webpage, press F12 key on your keyboard, it opens an inspect element window, on that window press Ctrl+F and in the search bar paste the xpath expression. Notice the search results. Change [2] to [3], you will notice a different element gets located.

Comment: Yes I am getting it little by little steadily. Finally I select the date. I am trying to select a time now:-

self.click_ele("css", "#out_time_modaltlbf_chosen")

This clicks on the dropdown, so this works. Now I am not able to choose and select a specific time stamp. For eg. I want to select / click 17:30. How do I do that, Shawn ?

Comment: Sorry, am afraid I can’t answer all your questions in one single post. We’ll be flooding the comments section this way. I suggest google “locating elements strategy in selenium” and you will get a plenty of articles. Read about it. If you are stuck still and need help with a particular issue, raise another question here.

Comment: Okay sure, I will raise a new one after giving it a try. Thank you Shawn.

Comment: Hi Shawn, could you please help me with another problem on this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78214471/select-valid-date-time-as-per-input-from-calendar-using-selenium-in-python?noredirect=1#comment137889343_78214471